Covariant Directional Derivative
How is the covariant directional derivative $\frac{D}{d\lambda}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\nabla_{\mu}$ in GR related to acceleration? I am motivated to ask this question because I’ve seen it stated that in the case of an observer hovering above a black hole in a Schwarzschild geometry. Then the acceleration the observer feels is $a^{\mu}=\frac{D}{d\lambda}u^{\mu}$, where $u^{\mu}$ is the four-velocity of the observer.

$\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}$ is the 4-velocity $u^{\mu}$ of the observer. So the definition of acceleration becomes $a^{\mu}=u^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}u^{\mu}$. The free falling condition is that $a^{\mu}=0$. In a way, the covariant directional derivative measures the rate of change along the worldline of the observer.

It looks like you've defined $u^\mu$ as a tangent vector of a curve, rather than as a vector field (such as $A^\mu(x)$.) Could you elaborate on how you define the covariant derivative of $u^\mu(\lambda)$? (Should $\nabla_\nu u^\mu$ be understood as the derivative of a "continuation" of $u^\mu$ to a neighborhood of $x^\mu(\lambda)$? It might be worth reassuring readers that the result is independent of the choice of continuation, or including what conditions are necessary to ensure, e.g., consistency with the equations of motion.)

@TLDR Idk if this answers your question, but the parameter $\lambda$ can be thought of as a scalar field satisfying $u^a\partial_a \lambda = 1$, which follows from the fact that $u^a$ is the tangent vector on the worldline of the observer : $u^a=dx^a/d\lambda$. One can even adopt a coordinate system $x^a=(\lambda, q^i) $ in which case, $u^a=(1, 0,0,0)$. $\nabla_bu^a$ is the covariant derivative in the usual sense, i.e. $\nabla_bu^a =\partial_bu^a +\Gamma^a_{bc}u^c$

It sounds like implicitly, you have extended the tangent vector $u^a$ and scalar parameter $\lambda$ to an open neighborhood of the world line (originally parametrized by $\lambda$). Does that sound accurate?

Yes. The $u$ can be considered as the unit vector field associated to a time like congruence. The trajectories are the world lines of family of observers
